# WPF DataGrid centering columns messes up MahApps styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, mahapps.metro

I have a `DataGrid` that I am using the `MahApps` styles on. I have a column that needs to be centered; each time I create a style the cells associated with that column look differently when selected.

The following is my DataGrid XAML.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DiariesForSelectedProject}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Number}"
                            Width="Auto"
                            IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment"
                            Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=d}" 
                            Width="Auto" 
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspector"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Inspector}" 
                            Width="Auto"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Diary Status"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                            Width="Auto"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsOwner}"
                                    Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                                    Value="Supervisor Returned" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Red" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsOwner}"
                                    Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                                    Value="Office Returned" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Red" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Instead of using the CellStyle I have above, I have also tried the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderDataGridCellStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then referenced that style for my cell. However, the end result is the same both times. The column is centered, but the DataGrid cell has a different appearance when the row is selected.

[image]

Can someone help me out with how to properly center a column and not mess up the MahApps style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this using `XAMLSpy` and looking at the row. It turns out that the background color was being reset on each cell that the style was applied to. In order to resolve it, I just wrapped the content presenter in a grid and set the background color to transparent.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderDataGridCellStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```